# Trouble with `has_many through:` Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I'm setting up a User, Website, and Tag model, but am unsure of the correct associations?

This is a CRUD app in which I want to allow the User to create a 'website' (a bookmark essentially) and be able to add a 'tag' to that website so that websites can be filtered.

I have three tables: `User`, `Website`, `Tag`

I want, User to have many websites, website has many tags, tags belong to website, and a user has many tags through websites.

I already have the following models set up:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :websites
  has_many :tags, through: :websites
end

class Website < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :website
end
```

I am saving the tag via a post request:

```
post '/websites' do
  if logged_in?
    if params[:content] == ""
      redirect to "/websites/new"
    else
      @website = current_user.websites.build(content: params[:content])
      binding.pry
      @tag = current_user.tags.build(content: params[:dropdown])
      if @website.save && @tag.save
        redirect to "/websites/#{@website.id}"
      else
        redirect to "/websites/new"
      end
    end
  else
    redirect to '/login'
  end
end
```

When I check `params` at the `binding.pry` it gives me as expected:

```
{content=>"tryingtoaddtag.com", "dropdown"=>"Clothing"}
```

My expectation is to be able to save an instance of a user and then use `@user.tags` to show all tags associated with that user's websites. I can't quite figure out where I'm messing up. Thank you.

Comment: what do you get from `@user.tags`?

Comment: So I created a website with a tag of `Travel` and when I drop into `pry` and type `Tag.last` it gives me that as expected. But `User.all[0].tags` is giving me an empty array. I double checked that `User.all[0]` gives me the correct user that is creating the website/tag

Comment: Can you try `User.first.tags.to_sql` and see if it correctly joining the tables in sql?

Comment: So this is what it gave back:
    "SELECT \"tags\".* FROM \"tags\" INNER JOIN \"websites\" ON \"tags\".\"website_id\" = \"websites\".\"id\" WHERE \"
websites\".\"user_id\" = 1"

Comment: Can you try `current_user.tags.build(content: params[:dropdown], website: @website)`? if that not work you can first save @website and then pass website id while building.

Comment: @AustinBurke Please have a look at given answer below, may be that's you want, feel free to accept/upvote answer if it you, as well as for future SO searchers.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [Article](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-delegate/) and then try this:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :website
  delegate :user, :to => :website, :allow_nil => true
end
```

If this doesn't work. Use scope in `User` model with

```
def tags
 Tags.where(website_id: self.websites.pluck(:id))
end
```

Comment: No luck still. I shouldn't have to create a `tags` method if I'm using a join though should I?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a website has_many :tags

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :websites

  def user_tags
    Tag.joins(:website).where(websites: {user_id:  self.id})
  end

end

class Website < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :website
end
```

Query -

```
user = User.first
user.user_tags
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with following,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :websites 
end

class Website < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :website
  scope :user_tags, ->(user) { joins(:website).where(websites: {user_id:  user}) }
end
```

Query will look like, (for `@user` object)

```
Tag.user_tags(@user)
```